# How to find points at infinity in projective coordinates for the $x^2 -3xy-2y^2-x+1=0$

Tags: elliptic-curves

How to find points at infinity in projective coordinates for this algebraic curve $x^2 -3xy-2y^2-x+1=0$

I don't know how to start! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you find a curve in projective space, such that this affine curve is just a projection in an affine chart?